# What is wrong with this jquery each() select options?

Tags: jquery, each

I have the below function,

```
function setDropdownValue(dropdownId,selectedValue){
            $('#'+dropdownId+' option').each(function(){
                 if ($(this).val().toLowerCase()==selectedValue.toLowerCase()){
                     //found the option i  was looking for, do what i want
                     $(this).val(selectedValue);
                 }
            });
        }
```

And i am passing `dropdownId=$('#dp1")` and `selectedValue='Bat'` and for some reason my each() function is not getting executed.. I am calling like this `setDropdownValue($("#dp1"),'Bat');`Am i missing something??

Comment: Aside from the toLowerCase that you've got, is there a reason you're doing the each function at all?  You can set the value of the select by doing $('#'+dropdownId).val(selectedValue);  You are also calling the .val() function on the option, not on the select.

Comment: how you are calling...??through whick event...??

Answer (score 3):

`dropdownId` should just be a string, why are you passing `$('#dp1")` which is a jQuery object?

You should just pass `'dp1'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('#dp1 option').each(function(){
             if ($(this).val().toLowerCase()==selectedValue.toLowerCase()){
                 //found the option i  was looking for, do what i want
                 $(this).val(selectedValue);
             }
        });
```

why need to use dropdownId....sometimes it lead some conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to write your function as follows, as this will maintain your lowercase logic

```
function setDropdown(id, value){
   var dropdown = $('#' + id);
   dropdown.find('option').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()){
           dropdown.val($(this).val());
           return;
       }
   });
}
```

I would call this function like so...

```
setDropdown('myDropdownId', '0000-AABBCC');
```

I tend to believe you should set the 'val' on the select, not on the options themselves.  I've seen quirks before with that method.